# Scraping works fine until appended to list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am a beginner trying to scrape bitcoin price history, everything works fine until I try to append it to a list, as nothing ends up being appended to the list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20190821'
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

priceDiv = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'table-responsive'})
rows = priceDiv.find_all('tr')

data = []
i = 0

for row in rows:
    temp = []
    tds = row.findChildren()

    for td in tds:
        temp.append(td.text)
    if i > 0:
        temp[0] = temp[0].replace(',', '')
        temp[6] = temp[6].replace(',', '')
        if temp[5] == '-':
            temp[5] = 0
        else:
            temp[5] = temp[5].replace(',', '')
        data.append({'date': datetime.strptime(temp[0], '%b %d %Y'),
                     'open': float(temp[1]),
                     'high': float(temp[2]),
                     'low': float(temp[3]),
                     'close': float(temp[4]),
                     'volume': float(temp[5]),
                     'market_cap': float(temp[6])})

        i += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If I try to print df or data it is just empty.

Comment: Unindent `i += 1`

Comment: @Selcuk Wow haha, how did I miss that, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, you need to increment i outside that the check for > 0.

Secondly, have you considered using pandas `.read_html()`. That will do the hard work for you.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20190821'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
              Date     Open*      ...            Volume    Market Cap
0     Aug 20, 2019  10916.35      ...       15053082175  192530283565
1     Aug 19, 2019  10350.28      ...       16038264603  195243306008
2     Aug 18, 2019  10233.01      ...       12999813869  185022920955
3     Aug 17, 2019  10358.72      ...       13778035685  182966857173
4     Aug 16, 2019  10319.42      ...       20228207096  185500055339
5     Aug 15, 2019  10038.42      ...       22899115082  184357666577
6     Aug 14, 2019  10889.49      ...       19990838300  179692803424
7     Aug 13, 2019  11385.05      ...       16681503537  194762696644
8     Aug 12, 2019  11528.19      ...       13647198229  203441494985
9     Aug 11, 2019  11349.74      ...       15774371518  205941632235
10    Aug 10, 2019  11861.56      ...       18125355447  202890020455
11    Aug 09, 2019  11953.47      ...       18339989960  211961319133
12    Aug 08, 2019  11954.04      ...       19481591730  213788089212
13    Aug 07, 2019  11476.19      ...       22194988641  213330426789
14    Aug 06, 2019  11811.55      ...       23635107660  205023347814
15    Aug 05, 2019  10960.74      ...       23875988832  210848822060
16    Aug 04, 2019  10821.63      ...       16530894787  195907875403
17    Aug 03, 2019  10519.28      ...       15352685061  193233960601
18    Aug 02, 2019  10402.04      ...       17489094082  187791090996
19    Aug 01, 2019  10077.44      ...       17165337858  185653203391
20    Jul 31, 2019   9604.05      ...       16631520648  180028959603
21    Jul 30, 2019   9522.33      ...       13829811132  171472452506
22    Jul 29, 2019   9548.18      ...       13791445323  169880343827
23    Jul 28, 2019   9491.63      ...       13738687093  170461958074
24    Jul 27, 2019   9871.16      ...       16817809536  169099540423
25    Jul 26, 2019   9913.13      ...       14495714483  176085968354
26    Jul 25, 2019   9809.10      ...       15821952090  176806451137
27    Jul 24, 2019   9887.73      ...       17398734322  175005760794
28    Jul 23, 2019  10346.75      ...       17851916995  176572890702
29    Jul 22, 2019  10596.95      ...       16334414913  184443440748
           ...       ...      ...               ...           ...
2276  May 27, 2013    133.50      ...                 -    1454029510
2277  May 26, 2013    131.99      ...                 -    1495293015
2278  May 25, 2013    133.10      ...                 -    1477958233
2279  May 24, 2013    126.30      ...                 -    1491070770
2280  May 23, 2013    123.80      ...                 -    1417769833
2281  May 22, 2013    122.89      ...                 -    1385778993
2282  May 21, 2013    122.02      ...                 -    1374013440
2283  May 20, 2013    122.50      ...                 -    1363709900
2284  May 19, 2013    123.21      ...                 -    1363204703
2285  May 18, 2013    123.50      ...                 -    1379574546
2286  May 17, 2013    118.21      ...                 -    1373723882
2287  May 16, 2013    114.22      ...                 -    1325726787
2288  May 15, 2013    111.40      ...                 -    1274623813
2289  May 14, 2013    117.98      ...                 -    1243874488
2290  May 13, 2013    114.82      ...                 -    1315710011
2291  May 12, 2013    115.64      ...                 -    1281982625
2292  May 11, 2013    117.70      ...                 -    1284207489
2293  May 10, 2013    112.80      ...                 -    1305479080
2294  May 09, 2013    113.20      ...                 -    1254535382
2295  May 08, 2013    109.60      ...                 -    1264049202
2296  May 07, 2013    112.25      ...                 -    1240593600
2297  May 06, 2013    115.98      ...                 -    1249023060
2298  May 05, 2013    112.90      ...                 -    1288693176
2299  May 04, 2013     98.10      ...                 -    1250316563
2300  May 03, 2013    106.25      ...                 -    1085995169
2301  May 02, 2013    116.38      ...                 -    1168517495
2302  May 01, 2013    139.00      ...                 -    1298954594
2303  Apr 30, 2013    144.00      ...                 -    1542813125
2304  Apr 29, 2013    134.44      ...                 -    1603768865
2305  Apr 28, 2013    135.30      ...                 -    1488566728

[2306 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know that was a thing, this is obviously way more efficient, is there any cases where you would do all the webscraping instead of this? Would you always use this pd.read_html() first before trying to webscrape?

Comment: IF I notice the tags  are , `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, in the html, then yes, the first thing I try is `pd.read_html()`. Pandas is actually using bs4 under the hood, and is basically iterating through it the same way as you are above by finding the `<table>` tag, then `.find_all('tr')`, etc. If the data however is not within `<table>` tags, then you'll need to do it the long way.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I am having another problem where when I graph the data using matplotlib the x axis is so crowded that it is unreadable, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Ya easy fix. You could make the font size smaller, or rotate the labels, or do both for you x labels.

Comment: do: `ax = plt.gca()`
`df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='High',ax=ax)`

Comment: or: `dates = list(df['Date'])`
`plt.plot( 'Date', 'High', data=df, marker='', color='blue', linewidth=1)`
`plt.xticks(dates[::100], rotation=45, ha='right')`
`plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: Thanks, using just plt.xticks(dates[::100], rotation=45, ha='right') worked for me. I had like over 2000 data points so spacing it by 100 worked perfectly, that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks